# an error occurred forwarding 3000 -> 443: error forwarding port 443 to pod

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio-gateway, google-anthos-service-mesh

We are getting below mentioned error while doing a port forward on istio-gateway service for a dotnet application container that is accepting traffic on port 443.

Error : E1123 05:39:22.388987   14792 portforward.go:409] an error occurred forwarding 3000 -> 443: error forwarding port 443 to pod a6a68b8b584896b49f5139ea5723e8a4ba5e9cf299136629fb4406e5bd2a1f33, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-7ad6dc68-d8e7-ca83-ac5f-f19f1cadc460": read tcp4 127.0.0.1:39588->127.0.0.1:443: read: connection reset by peer
error: lost connection to pod

We are in the process of migrating a dotnet application from an existing Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster to a new GKE cluster. Currently, the application is accessible via an internal load balancer using port 443 and is functioning properly. In the new cluster, we have integrated Google's Anthos Service Mesh (ASM) and Istio, and we are exposing the application through istio-gateway.
The deployment of the application was successful, and it operates as expected when we perform a port forward directly on the application container pod. However, when attempting to browse the application after port forwarding on the Istio Gateway service, we encounter the error. We have experimented with exposing the application on port 80 or using a random port, but this results in a similar error.

Comment: Can you add a few more details on the commands you are running?

Comment: Below is the gateway service spec :  
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-gateway/gateway1
  hosts:
  - sampledns.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /api/v1/test
    route:
    - destination:
        host: test-stg
        port:
          number: 443
When the app is exposed on port 80 we are able to connect to the app service deployment. but exposing on port 443 it is unable to connect to appl service and  we don't see any logs.